# What does it refer to?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Musically and tonally, being funny is split in two: it starts as outward-looking, wry and analytical about finding love during the culture wars and becomes simplistic and clearly diaristic about his own romantic relationships. “I wanted to write about the culture war but also write about being in love and ‘Yeah, fuck all that, let’s kiss’ or shit that’s a bit cringe,” Healy tells me. “Because I’m so bored of ‘That’s a really good take, bro.’ Like, try saying something nice. It’s really fucking hard.”
>
> A problem facing love at large is the idea that modern masculinity is in crisis. Mass shootings and violence appear on ‘Looking for Somebody to Love’, a **dark** and upbeat 80s-inspired song that could soundtrack a Black Mirror episode about what happens when a man can’t convince a woman to date him. “You’ve gotta show me how to push, if you don’t want a shove are the words of a young man, already damned, looking for somebody to love,” Healy sings. The lighter side of a confused masculinity is echoed on the lead single, ‘Part of the Band’: “I like my men like I like my coffee/Full of soy milk and so sweet it won’t offend anybody”.

Can someone help me? I was reading this interview today and a bit confused about what **dark** here refers to. Does it refer to the lyrics of the song or the sound of the song?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It refers to the song in general.

> "Looking for Somebody to Love" is *a dark and upbeat 80s-inspired **song*** that could soundtrack a Black Mirror episode about what happens when a man can’t convince a woman to date him.

It doesn't elaborate what *dark* points to specifically. It could refers to the song's unpleasant/disturbing language, or to its melancholic/sad melody, or to both.